# Why are the values ​shown differently?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I try to set value  by tag input 
Example
for this case I type 1000.0009 (In input text)
The valid values is need to be 1000.0001
but value is not correct in tag input  but tag outside is correct

How to fix this?

I need to same value when change

Default

[image]

Set Value

[image]

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <section>
      <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1 class="text-info">Data binding demo</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter your name"
            [ngModel]="name | number: '1.4'"
            (change)="updateNumber($event.target.value)"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center">
        <h1>{{ number | number: "1.4" }}</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  number: string = "";

  updateNumber(OldNumber: string) {
    let newNumber = parseFloat(OldNumber).toFixed(4);
    this.number = newNumber;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is because `toFixed(4)`. Remove it or use `toFixed(5)` instead.

Comment: @AliAhmadi it not working , when I set  value in inputbox is have five digit  , it not four digit.

Comment: Removed `toFixed(4)` in front of `parseFloat(OldNumber)` and still not working?

Comment: not working , can you edit code  please? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-data-one-way-binding-mtxizb?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&hideNavigation=1 @AliAhmadi

Comment: Hmm... Also you need to use `number` instead of `number: "1.4"`.

Comment: I think now is OK. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-data-one-way-binding-er17gk?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&hideNavigation=1

Comment: In your last code. I type 1000.00006 it not 1000.0001 in input text. I need  digit 4 bro @AliAhmadi

Answer (score 1):

Your `ngModel` of input tag is referring to wrong property. Use `number` property instead.

```
    <input
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter your name"
        [ngModel]="number | number: '1.4'"
        (change)="updateNumber($event.target.value)"
     />
```

Adding stackblitz link for reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7nduih?file=src/app/app.component.html. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: In your code , I type  set  10.0000  in input and outside is 10.0000  and when i type 9  input and outside is 10.0001  that correct  after that I type 2   in input  is 10.00012 but outside is 10.0001  I need to get value same outside in input text How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

This above situation is happening because the fraction digits after decimal point are not properly defined.

Make these code changes and verify:

```
 updateNumber(OldNumber: string) {
let newNumber = parseFloat(OldNumber).toFixed(5);
this.number = newNumber;}
```

---

```
<div class="text-center">
<h1>{{ number | number: "1.4-5" }}</h1></div>
```

Comment: it not working , when I set  value in inputbox is have five digit  , it not four digit.